# What does this expression mean and why is it used in any gan?

Tags: python, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

All gans use this expression before saving images. Why is it so?
[image]

Comment: Please post the code out of images.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: How do you expect us to know what this is for? We have no context for this code. Please read [ask].

Comment: i sent it because i care only about this small expression. should i still edit it?

Comment: Should you still edit it? Yes, to replace the image with text. And yes, to clarify your question. _Again_, please read [ask].

Comment: And _you_ might only care about that small expression, but we can't help you unless we understand what this code is doing. You need to provide enough context for that.

Comment: What are “gans”? Are you talking about GAN? Acronyms need to be capitalized in English to be understandable.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the original pictures have three channels of pixels (one for red pixels, one for green pixels, and one for blue pixels), each pixel having a value between -1 and 1. While this data presentation is useful to train neural networks, to save pictures as pngs it is required to have pixels with integer values ranging from 0 to 255 for each color channel.

Applying this operation therefore transform them into pictures where each pixel of each channel has a value between 0 and 255. Then, `.astype(np.uint8)` converts your pixels values to 8-bit integers, and you have your pixels with integer values ranging from 0 to 255 for each color channel.